# converting date string to utc time format javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, utc

i'm trying to convert this date string format "2014-12-04 12:00am" to a utc time with the format of "2014-11-29 01:00:12".

i'm using this function

```
 function formatDate(d){
          function addZero(n){
              return n < 10 ? '0' + n : '' + n;
          }

          return d.getUTCFullYear() +"-"+ addZero(d.getUTCMonth()+1) + "-" +addZero(d.getUTCDate()) + " " +
              addZero(d.getUTCHours()) + ":" + addZero(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + addZero(d.getUTCMinutes());
      }
```

for some reason when i pick 12am it's set the val to a 12pm and i'm not sure this function is working on all the possibilities

Comment: @BenjaminRay Your edits are being discussed here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289145/same-one-letter-edit-suggested-to-nearly-60-questions-should-i-alert-a-moderato?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this JS :

```
var d = new Date("2014-12-04 12:00 am");
var n = d.toUTCString();
alert(n); // Output: Wed, 03 Dec 2014 18:30:00 GMT
```

You can see this link : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_toutcstring

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
var utc =  moment.utc(new Date())
alert("UTC: " + utc.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss A'))//A for AM, PM
```